# How to avoid using sudo for certain programs under xrdp in Raspbian?

Tags: linux, xrdp

Background: I look after the Raspberry Pi version of Scratch for the Foundation. Mostly this is a matter of Smalltalk programming, VM developing and some very frustrating moments with shell scripts.

Right now I'm baffled and annoyed by what seems likely to be a unix permissions or related issue when using xrdp to connect to a Pi from any other machine. I know that it's not a problem directly with theSqueak VM since google has revealed quite a few other applications having similar looking issues. Part of my problem is that I don't know enough about this area to really know what to search for to narrow things down.

So, problem description - 
The current Scratch system runs on the Squeak Cog VM (see https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm), which amongst other things uses pthreads and needs to set the thread priority. That used to be something that required modifying some config but more recent (Raspbian) kernels have no problem with it.

*Except* when using xrdp, which is a pain because I mostly work with my Pi via xrdp to my iMac. To handle this I have to prepend a 'sudo -E' which is tolerable for a developer but not really good for general users. 
I have a similar problem with a trivial file copying command used in the VM make process as well, and that doesn't use any thread stuff nor priority work, but does require me to `sudo make` in a terminal window.

As an experiment I tried using tightvnc, to see if anything might work better. After reading the full install instructions (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) and adding the auto-startup init.d script etc, it seemed like maybe we were in luck because the sudo isn't needed! Hooray! Of course, I was a bit disappointed by the seemingly slower display handling, but never mind.

Sadly this isn't even close to the end of the story. I've recently been working on completing the support for the X composition input window system that allows Japanese and other non-Latin1 type language users to enter characters more easily. It's pretty clever, once you've installed iBus, Anthy, many fonts and done some setup. But, while it works perfectly well on a Pi with a direct display, and fine on an xrdp display (with the sudo to allow Scratch to run in the first place, of course) it simply won't work via vnc with or without a sudo.

Googling shows a large number of other applications having problems in odd ways with the relevant XCreateIC() call (see https://github.com/OpenSmalltalk/opensmalltalk-vm/blob/Cog/platforms/unix/vm-display-X11/sqUnixX11.c line:1659 for our usage) but nothing I can make much connection to vnc for. To add to the annoyance the combo window appears ok for Terminals!

To summarise-
direct display - no problems for either the pthread priority or the compo window
xrdp - needs sudo for pthreads priority but the compo window works ok
vnc - doesn't need sudo for pthread priority but compo window doesn't work.

What I need: help with finding out what causes these problems and maybe even solutions. A way to configure xrdp to not require 'sudo' would be nice.

Comment: I have not an answer, but I would download the editor [here](https://scratch.mit.edu/scratch2download/) to do it local and just copy the file over.

Comment: Sorry Peter, not a possible thing. The Pi does not run Flash, which is what Scratch2 is written in. The Pi release is based on (a heavily improved) original Scratch, which is written in Squeak Smalltalk. And of course it would be nice to find a solution to the problem for all the other applications that seem to be affected!

Comment: I mean don't do your Scratch development on the Pi but on your computer and only copy the resulting file over

Comment: Sorry again Peter but that's not at all where my problem lies. Writing a Scratch script on some other machine and then using it on a Pi is not an issue. The problem is that something in the way xrdp & vnc works prevents the Squeak VM from doing it's job, and that messes up using Scratch. It's not a Squeak/Scratch problem per se - you can google many other applications having similar seeming problems.

Answer (score 0):

To my delight a colleague found what appears to be a very effective answer to this; it seems that the /etc/pam.d/common-session file needs a single line adding.
Edit the file and add 
      session    required   pam_limits.so
This allows all the applications I have that previously had permission related problems to run under xrdp. Another Scratch user who had a similar issue using PuTTY reports that it solved that issue as well.